# UDPclient rate control in c#

Tags: c#, networking, udp, bandwidth, udpclient

Im sending multiple udp packets consecutively to a remote pc. the problem is, if the amount of data is too high, some device somewhere between the channel experience buffer overflow. i intent to limit/throttle/control sending rate of the udp packets. can somebody give me some guide on how to find the optimal rate sending interval?

By the way, please stop suggesting tcp over udp. the objective is not to send data reliably, but to measure maximum throughput.

Comment: If you really want to measure throughput then send as much as you can and count on the other side.  You don't have to throttle to measure max throughput.

Comment: @Daniel Mošmondor. i take it you dont have a clue on what the issues is. please dont spam.

Comment: Of course I don't have a clue since you said: *the objective is not to send data reliably, but to measure maximum throughput.* and as far is measuring is concerned, my proposal will do just this.

Comment: @DanielMošmondor Let me explain. If you send udp packets without some method of throttle, the packet will eventually overflow network element between endpoints. When that happens, the endpoint will just drop packets. When that happens, there is no way you could tell the bandwidth between endpoints. Not to mention, some network elements used by telco will detect that situation as packet spams and immediately drop every udp packet from that ip. There are also issue of efficiency.

Comment: @DanielMošmondor If you think you can measure the bandwidth by measuring how much data you can send, how can you measure the bandwidth when you can send data as much as 1gb per second on a cat 5 cable? If you believe you can send udp packet as much as you can and be able to measure the bandwidth by counting on the other side, show it to the world and prove me wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Trial and error. Point.

- Make up a secnod connection (UDP or TCP based) that you use ONLY to send control commands.
- Send stats there about missing packets etc. Then the sides can decide whether the data rate is too high.
- Possibly start low then up the data rate until you see missing packets.

NEVER (!) assume all packets will arrive. Means: you need (!) a way to reask for missing packets. Even under perfect cnoditions packets will get lost sometimes.

If loss is ok and only should be minimized, a statistical approach is pretty much the only way I see to handle this.

Comment: to be honest, the 'decide' thing is pretty easy for non-robot(human). representing the problem in mathematical way is nontrivia. is there any papers, research on this topic? what is the keyword that i should google? my background is not computer networking, so...

Comment: Check RTP protocols. The problem you face is standard in things like real time voice / video transfer. RTP is using UDP and there is a control protocol for stuff like this.

Answer (score 2):

Try this then:

- Start with packets of 1KB size (for example).
- For them, calculate how many packets per second will be OK to send - for example - 1GB ethernet = 100MBytes of raw bandwidth -> 100000 packets
- create a packed so first 4 bytes would be the serial number, rest could be anything - if you are testing here, fill it with zeroes or noise (random data)
- on sending side, create a packets and push them at the speed of RATE (previously calculated) for one second. calculate time spent, and `Sleep()` the rest of the time, waiting for new time slot.
- on receiving end, gather packets and look into their serial numbers.  if packets are missing, send (another connection) some info to the sender about it.
- sender, on info about lost packets, should do something like `RATE = RATE * .9` - reduce sending rate to 90% of a previous one
- sender should gradually increase rate (say 1%) every few seconds if it doesn't get any 'lost packets' message
- after some time you RATE will converge to something that you wanted in the first place

Some considerations:
- if back connection is TCP, you'll have some overhead there
- if back connection is UDP, you can also have dropped packets here (because you are flooding the channel) and sender could never know that packets are dropped
- algorithm above won't solve missing data issue or out-of-order data issue, it will just measure the throughput.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Have a look at my current implementation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167278/how-to-calculate-bandwidth-using-c. Corrent me if im wrong, from what i understand, if i send data for 1 second, and the receiver received data for 2 second, that means i have to readjust my sending rate until i get 1 second send and 1 second receive? pardon my language. im not good at explaining myself. this by the way, remind me of some papers on bandwidth estimation. one of em is pathload.thanks.

Comment: Well, it's time you bang your head into it - you have all the info you need, now experiment until you get it right.  Programmers do that from time to time, it's fun and it's most valuable experience.  Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

Despite your proposal that I don't suggest TCP over UDP, I have to.  In same paragraph you are stating that the main purpose of your test is to measure throughput - that is bandwidth - and only way to do it properly without to re-invent whole TCP stack is to actually USE TCP stack.

Large parts of TCP are designed to work with flow control issues, and when TCP streams are used, you'll get exactly what you need - maximum bandwidth for given connection, with ease and without 'warm water inventing'.

If this answer doesn't suit you, that probably means that you have to re-state your requirements on the problem.  They are in conflict.

Comment: sigh. what im trying to achieve is to measure how much data can flow through a channel. for example, on 1 mb channel, the maximum data can flow through the channel is 1mb. the bandwidth that you can get using tcp is the good data excluding packet headers, excluding the data that have to be retransmitted. with tcp, you ALWAYS have lower results that what it is.plus with udp, you can get more statistics than just bandwidth. i appreciate that you want to help. but please.

Comment: UDP has headers also.  I every protocol you'll have 'slack'.

Comment: of course udp have headers. i never said udp doesnt have headers, have i? but can you track how much data headers consume? can you track how much data in tcp has been retransmitted?

Comment: The problem with tcp is the inability to track how much packet is lost. The other problem with tcp for bandwidth measurement is data retransmission and tcp slow start. For example, you are sending 100Mbits of data over 100Mbits/s channel. The channel have packet loss rate of 50%. If using tcp, the results would be the channel is 50Mbits/s, which is wrong. The primary concern is not how much 'good' data the end user received, but how much bandwidth the channel can transmit. When a telco said that they provide 100Mbps/s bandwidth, they dont mean the user would received 100Mbps/s 'good' data.